# Reactjs state not render to update the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What i am trying to do is when a user click on button a new table row to be added:-

**Child Component:-**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Card, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import Aux from "../hoc/_Aux";

const ObservationsForm = (props) => {

  return (
    <Aux>
      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <Card.Title as="h5">New Inspection</Card.Title>
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="table-responsive">
              <table className="table table-bordered table-center">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Observation</th>
                    <th>Recommendation</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Attachments</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {props.observations.map((o, i) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{i + 1}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
                          </Form.Group>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control
                              as="textarea"
                              rows={3}
                              list="browsers"
                            />
                          </Form.Group>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                          <br />
                          <br />
                          <Form.Control as="select">
                            <option>Low</option>
                            <option>Meduim</option>
                            <option>High</option>
                          </Form.Control>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <br />
                          <br />
                          <i className="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                  <tr>
                    <td colSpan="5" style={{ border: "0px" }}>
                      <button
                        className="w-100"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          e.preventDefault();

                          const currentState = props.observations;
                          currentState.push({
                            observation: "",
                            recommendation: "",
                            priority: "low",
                            attachements: [],
                          });

                          props.setObservation(currentState);
                        }}
                      >
                        Add More
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

            <Button variant="primary" className="col-12" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Aux>
  );
};

export default ObservationsForm;
```

**Parent Component:-**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ObservationsForm from "../components/ObservationsForm";

import Aux from "../hoc/_Aux";

const NewInspection = () => {
  const [observationsState, setObservationsState] = useState([
    { observation: "", recommendation: "", priority: "low", attachments: [] },
  ]);

  return (
    <Aux>
      <ObservationsForm
        observations={observationsState}
        setObservation={(data) => setObservationsState(data)}
      />
    </Aux>
  );
};

export default NewInspection;
```

When I click on add button the DOM does not update until i right click on chrome then select inspect , DOM get updated.

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not updating the state correctly. You are mutating it directly which is not how you update the state. Mutating the state directly doesn't causes a re-render.

From [`React Docs:`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is
> being applied. **It should not be directly mutated**. Instead, **changes
> should be represented by building a new object** based on the input from
> state and props

#### Solution

Change your `onClick` event handler as shown below:

```
onClick={(e) => {
   e.preventDefault();

   // create a new array
   const updatedObservations = [...props.observations];

   // push the new object in the new array
   updatedObservations.push({
      observation: "",
      recommendation: "",
      priority: "low",
      attachements: [],
   });

   // pass the new array to state updater function
   props.setObservation(updatedObservations);
}}
```